# href does not work when link returned from function

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, onclick, href

The following works:

```
<a id="showDirectionsMapLink" href="#" onclick="href='comgooglemaps://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Google,+1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA+94043&daddr=Google+Inc,+345+Spear+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&center=37.422185,-122.083898&zoom=10';">test</a>
```

It opens in the google maps app.

The following does not work:

```
<a id="showDirectionsMapLink" href="#" onclick="showDirectionsMap();">test2</a>
```

showDirectionsMap() function will get the location of the accounts selected and return the same exact string as above.
href='comgooglemaps://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Google,+1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA+94043&daddr=Google+Inc,+345+Spear+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&center=37.422185,-122.083898&zoom=10'

Nothing happens

Comment: Setting the links href won't trigger a click, it just changes the href. You can use `window.location.href` to make it redirect, or just programmatically trigger the `click`

Comment: actually the below code is showing the alert with the string from the function...
<a id="showDirectionsMapLink" href="#" onclick="alert(showDirectionsMap());">test2</a>

Comment: The string returned by the `onclick` code isn't used for anything. It doesn't become the href of the link.

Comment: I tried the window.location.href but it does not direct me to the google maps app...it shows me a page from salesforce that the url does not work.
This is in a visual force page in salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the URL returned by the function to be used, you have to assign it to `this.href`, just like you did in the version where you used a literal string.

```
<a id="showDirectionsMapLink" href="#" onclick="this.href = showDirectionsMap();">test2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks
This is within a visual force in Salesforce. So when I use the code you posted it will direct me to a blank page within my salesforce application. Is there a way around that?

Comment: I'm not sure why it works differently from your first example. Is there an error in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<a id="showDirrectionsMapLink">your link</a>
```

JS (uses JQuery):

```
function forceLink(event){
  event.preventEvent();
  event.stopPropagination();
  var link = 'http://google.com'; // whatever you want
  window.location.href = link; // automaticly forces the browser to this location
}

$('#showDirrectionsMapLink').on('click' forceLink);
```

if you want to use a onClick on the a tag, you need to stop standard execution and redirect by hand. the standard execution reads the href before your changes